# How to make a UITextview and a UIImageView scrollable

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, ios5

I have put an UIImageView and a UITextView in a UIScrollView. The result is that when I scroll, the text scrolls but the image stays on the same place.

Is it possible to make the UIImageView and UITextView to scroll as a whole? Can this be done using the storyboard?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason that you are only scrolling the text is that the UITextView has its own UIScrollView and you are only scrolling the UITextViews internal scroll view.

---

To achieve what you are looking for you need to:

- Disable scrolling in the UITextView
- Make the UITextView big enough to cover all the text
- Make the UIScrollViews contentSize big enough to cover both the UIImageView and the UITextView
- Layout the UIImageView and the UITextView in the UIScrollView

### Disable scrolling in the UITextView

Set `scrollingEnabled` to false on your textview, this can be done directly in the storyboard.

### Resize the UITextView

The text view could cover any length of text and without knowing what text is being set, you can't set the correct size. I.e, you will need to set the size in code when the text is set in the UITextView.

### Resize the contentSize

See above (if you don't know the height of the UITextView you can't know the content size).

### Layout the UIImageView and the UITextView in the UIScrollView

You can however layout the UIImageView and the UITextView in the storyboard and only change the `bounds` of the text view and the `contentSize` of the scrollView when the text is set.

---

### View hierarchy

The image below shows how your view hierarchy should look when you are finished. The frame of the **scrollView** is **blue**. Its **content** is **red** and is bigger than the frame. Within lies the **image view (yellow)** and the **text view (green)**.

[image]

Comment: done, now nothing scrolls, seems like a have yet to learn how uiscrollview works

Comment: I've updated my answer with an explanation of the view hierarchy. Hope it helps you understand how UIScrollView works